# Log-Structured Filesystem -- why do we need an explicit, scattered inode map?

Tags: data-structures, operating-systems, memory-hardware, filesystems

From [OSTEP Chp. 43](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/file-lfs.pdf):

> The imap is a structure that takes an inode number
> as input and produces the disk address of the most recent version of the inode

This makes sense to me as a solution to the problem of LFS scattering needing to keep track of inodes.

> It could live on a fixed part of the disk, of course. Unfortunately, as it
> gets updated frequently, this would then require updates to file structures
> to be followed by writes to the imap, and hence performance would suffer
> (i.e., there would be more disk seeks, between each update and the fixed
> location of the imap).
> Instead, LFS places chunks of the inode map right next to where it is
> writing all of the other new information. Thus, when appending a data
> block to a file k, LFS actually writes the new data block, its inode, and a
> piece of the inode map all together onto the disk

This doesn't.

> The checkpoint region contains pointers to (i.e., addresses of) the latest pieces of the inode map, and thus the inode map
> pieces can be found by reading the CR first. Note the checkpoint region
> is only updated periodically (say every 30 seconds or so), and thus performance is not ill-affected.

We end up with two levels of indirection, pointers to the pieces of the inode map, and the inode map that points to the inodes (right next to them). Why not just have the checkpoint region container pointers to the latest inodes, instead of having inode map "chunks" that must be read first to read the inode (which is likely just the next block over)?

As an aside, it states this problem:

> There is one other serious problem in LFS that the inode map solves,
> known as the recursive update problem [Z+12]. The problem arises
> in any file system that never updates in place (such as LFS), but rather
> moves updates to new locations on the disk.
> Specifically, whenever an inode is updated, its location on disk changes.
> If we hadn’t been careful, this would have also entailed an update to
> the directory that points to this file, which then would have mandated
> a change to the parent of that directory, and so on, all the way up the file
> system tree.
> LFS cleverly avoids this problem with the inode map. Even though
> the location of an inode may change, the change is never reflected in the
> directory itself; rather, the imap structure is updated while the directory
> holds the same name-to-inode-number mapping. Thus, through indirection, LFS avoids the recursive update problem.

which I think is solved even without inode map "chunks", and just what I'm proposing.